# Get all strings with same beginning and end and any number of the same letter in between

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to search in text for words that have the same start and end letter and any number of the same letter in between (should also be case-insensitive) e.g. lol, lool, Loool, loooooool etc. should all be captured.

I want to filter a Pandas dataframe for these words.
e.g. `df[df.message.str.contains('lol', case=False)]`

Comment: you want to do that with pandas only?

Comment: Yes, the `message` column are strings of text.

Comment: And what about `LL`? Or just `L` (starts and ends with the same letter)?

Comment: What should be matching cases for "abracadabra"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not necessary for my purposes

Comment: So, what is the code that does not work? `lol` is not going to work for sure. What patterns did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Using back-references, for example:

```
message_list = ['lol', 'look', 'looloo', 'lool', 'Loool', 'LaoL', 'loooooool']

import re

for word in message_list:
    m = re.match(r'^(.)(.)\2*\1$', word, re.IGNORECASE)
    if m:
        print(word, "matched")
```

Gives:

```
lol matched
lool matched
Loool matched
loooooool matched
```

`\1` matches whatever matched in the *first* parentheses group, `\2` the second, and so on.

Comment: `.` will match any char, not just a letter.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: true, but the question says "text", which could be anything.  Could use `\w` which includes numerics and an underscore, or `[A-Z]` instead if required.  The question is a little vague on that.